# How to set a gradient color for the "border" when its at 100% by Vue - Custom css package

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-css-donut-chart#usage-with-all-the-available-props to set the "border" around images based on progress.
The problem is that I need to set a gradient color for the "border" when it is at 100%, and the props don't allow me to do that. So what I tried instead to achieve this is the following:

```
if(this.sections[0].value = 50) {
    this.sections[0].color = "transparent"
    this.sections[1].color = "transparent"
    let grad = document.querySelector(".cdc")
    grad.classList.add("border-gradient")
    console.log(grad)
}
```

I am using this component at multiple places throughout the app, and the gradient color is only applied at one place:

```
<Home>
<sidebar/> <-----

<router-view />
</Home>
```

### Main.js

```
import Donut from "vue-css-donut-chart";
import "vue-css-donut-chart/dist/vcdonut.css";
Vue.use(Donut);
```

### Donut component

```
<template>
<div>
     <vc-donut
          :sections="sections"
          :size="size"
          :start-angle="angle"
          :thickness="thickness"
          :foreground="'#D4DDFC85'"
        >
        <b-img v-if="profilePic" class="object-fit-contain rounded-circle p-1 m-0" :width="width" :src="profilePic"/>
        </vc-donut>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
import backend from "@/services/backend.js"

export default {
    props: ["profilePic", "size", "width", "thickness"],
 data: () => {
    return {
        me: null,
        angle: null,
      sections: [
        { value: 0, color: "#4ECB62" },
        { value: 0, color: "#223C9B" },
      ],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
      this.fetch_me()
  },



  methods: {
      async fetch_me() {
          this.me = (await backend.me()).data
         
          
       
         if(this.me.roles.indexOf('investor') != -1 && this.me.roles.indexOf('homeowner') != -1) {
            // Set values for homeowner depending on amount of listed properties
           /*  if(this.me.homes.length == 100) {
                 this.sections[1].value = 50
             } else if (this.me.homes.length >= 25) {
                 this.sections[1].value = 40
             } else if (this.me.homes.length >= 5) {
                 this.sections[1].value = 35
             } else {
                 this.sections[1].value = 25
             }*/

             this.sections[1].value = 50 
               this.sections[0].value = 50
               if(this.sections[0].value = 50) {
                   this.sections[0].color = "transparent"
                   this.sections[1].color = "transparent"
                   let grad = document.querySelector(".cdc")
                   grad.classList.add("border-gradient")
                   console.log(grad)
               }
            // Set the correct angle depending on the value (Investor & Homeowner)
                 if(this.sections[0].value == 40 || this.sections[1].value == 40) {
                    return this.angle = 35
                 } else if (this.sections[0].value == 50 || this.sections[1].value == 50) {
                    return this.angle = 0
                 } else if (this.sections[0].value == 35 || this.sections[1].value == 35) {
                    return this.angle = 90
                 }  else if (this.sections[0].value == 25 || this.sections[1].value == 25) {
                    return this.angle = 25
                 }
            
          } else if(this.me.roles.indexOf('homeowner') != -1) {
            if(this.me.homes.length == 100) {
                 this.sections[1].value = 100
             } else if (this.me.homes.length >= 25) {
                 this.sections[1].value = 85
             } else if (this.me.homes.length >= 5) {
                 this.sections[1].value = 65
             } else {
                 this.sections[1].value = 50
             }
        
    
            // Set the correct angle depending on the value (Homeowner)
                if(this.sections[1].value == 50) {
                    return this.angle = 90
                } else if(this.sections[1].value == 65) {
                    return this.angle = 62
                } else if(this.sections[1].value == 85) {
                    return this.angle = 27
                } else {
                    return 0
                }
          } else if(this.me.roles.indexOf('investor') != -1) {
              this.sections[0].value = 50
              if(this.sections[0].value == 50) {
                this.sections[0].value = 50;
              }
              // Set the correct angle depending on the value (Investor)
              if(this.sections[0].value == 50) {
                    return this.angle = 90
                } 
          }
      },

  }
}
</script>

The console.log(grad) shows that the class is added to the element, but the CSS isn't applied.
```

Example of use of the donut(ProfileImageRings) component

```
<profile-image-rings v-if="user.picture" :width="160" :size="170" :thickness="7" :profilePic="user.picture"/>
```

### custom.scss

```
.border-gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #223C9B 0%, #4ECB62 100%) !important;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your approach?

Comment: @Mythos 
The problem is that the class "grad" that I add with javascript, gets added to the element, but the style is never applied to the component throughout the application (except for the one component in the sidebar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem was simply because I'm using a `querySelector` which only
> returns the first element with matching selector.

Solution to this problem is to change from `querySelector` to `getElementsByClassName` and then loop through the length of elements with the matching class, and there apply the other class to the elements.

```
this.sections[1].value = 50 
   this.sections[0].value = 50
   if(this.sections[0].value = 50) {
   this.sections[0].color = "transparent"
   this.sections[1].color = "transparent"
   let grad = document.getElementsByClassName("cdc")
      for(let i = 0; i < grad.length; i++) {
          grad[i].classList.add("border-gradient")
   }     
}
```